# Why can't Sass find the element of my color lookup mapping?

Tags: sass

I can't figure out why map-get does not return the expected results:

```
$buttonColors: (blue: lighten(blue, 25%), grey: lighten(gray, 40%));

@debug map-get($buttonColors, 'blue');
```

For some reason, this is returning `null` when I'm expecting it to return `#8080ff`.  This causes problems further down in my code because I can't pass a null value into functions like lighten or darken.

Comment: I agree - probably a typo mistake since $color is not one of the allowed color values.

Comment: Ok, now THAT helped. Sorta. I had to remove the interpolation from around the `$color` variable. Why would it have worked before though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping uses colors for its keys while you're telling Sass to look for an element that has a string for its key.  The color `blue` is not the same as the string `'blue'`.  As a result, the lookup fails and the `map-get()` function returns `NULL`.  All color keywords defined in the HTML/CSS specification have the type of *color* unless you quote them (or turn them into strings via interpolation).

You could just stop turning the second argument to map-get into a string, but it would be better if you just switched to always using strings for the keys of your mappings (using anything else just causes confusion and/or bugs).

```
$buttonColors: ('blue': lighten(blue, 25%), 'grey': lighten(gray, 40%));
```

Comment: Wow, apologies for the anger earlier. This solves it exactly. A coworker and I have been fighting this all day. Cheers

Comment: For what it's worth, this issue was brought up on the [sass issue tracker](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1721) a few months ago (though it's more of a complaint about how it is inconsistent with the nth function).  An error that the element you were requesting didn't exist would have been more helpful to you than just blindly passing it on as null.