# Using a variable from list in a function in each - scss

Tags: css, function, colors, sass

I'm making a list ($social) of social colors with their icon. The color, name and icon come from a sass list. In the code I can do an each to make a whole list of networks with their colors and icons.

```
@each $name,$color,$icon in $social{
    .social{
        &:before{ font-family: $social-font; }
        &.#{$name}{ background: #{$color}; color: color(white);
            @include shadow(rgba(black,0.25),black,false,true);
            &:hover{ background: darken($color,10%); }
            &:before{ content:"#{$icon}"; }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to make a hover where I can darken the base color.

```
&:hover{ background: darken($color,10%); }
```

But when I do so I get the following back:
"Error: $color: null is not a color for 'darken'"

Does anyone have an idea why and/or a workaround? There's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535869) but the person in that question ask why this happens in a single level array. This each uses a multidimensional array which looks like:

```
$social: (
  ("facebook",social(facebook),'7'),
  ("flickr",social(flickr),'w'),
  ("googleplus",social(googleplus),'r'),
  ("twitter",social(twitter),"'"),
  ("linkedin",social(linkedin),'*'),
  ("instagram",social(instagram),'9'),
  ("pinterest",social(pinterest),'K'),
  ("vkontakte",social(vkontakte),'&'),
  ("youtube",social(youtube),'"')
);
```

As you can see there are no quotes used in the color. the color goes through a function called "social" which does the following:

```
@function social($value){
    $color: map-get($social-colors, $value);
    @return $color;
}
```

No quotes neither.

In some way they could be in there, but also this:

```
&:hover{ background: darken(unquote($color),10%); }
```

does not make a difference.

Comment: To those voting to reopen, the problem cannot be reproduced:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/11703ff735e52bdf8780.  There's no point in reopening a question if it is just going to get closed again as "not reproducible".

Comment: It might look a little bit double, but it has its reason for not putting everything together in one array. I tried to get it in sassmeister and this is my fork of the current situation where you can see the output. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8c0e04eff5186b2825bd

Comment: You have a typographical error:  you're trying to access a key that doesn't exist in `$social-colors`.  See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185065/why-cant-sass-find-the-element-of-my-color-lookup-mapping